# 2010s cartoon/anime about two boys who find Lego mini figures and get teleported to another world, where they become heroes

Tags: story-identification, anime, cartoon, isekai

Made around the 2010s, it was about a boy who is in school. I believe he might have moved in. The main character's color scheme is red and he meets a friend whose color scheme is blue.

They enter a store and find Lego mini figures. The red guy takes the red one and the blue guy takes the blue one, and later on they get teleported to another world and become heroes. More characters find figures, and it ends up being red, blue, green, yellow, black and pink.

The Lego bricks found in the store are given out by the store owner for free and those kids weren’t the first ones to own those Legos. The people in the other world, who they save, are unaware of that.

Thinking about it, I am not sure if it was the Lego mini figure or it was a rectangle small toy, but in the other world they were based off of Lego characters.

Comment: Hopefully, I interpreted your question correctly. There are more than just the first two? And they all show up due to Lego?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This is hard to understand: "he might have moved in his color scheme is red"  Could you [edit] your question to make what you are saying more clear?

Comment: And I was trying to figure out what Lego had to do with a certain kind of fruit...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is ***[Tenkai Knights](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3401416/)*** (2013–2014).

[image]

From [MyAnimeList](https://myanimelist.net/anime/23067/Tenkai_Knights):

> *Tenkai Knights* is an original Canadian-Japanese anime series that officially aired in Cartoon Network in the United States on August 24, 2013 and in Canada on Teletoon on September 28, 2013. The anime premiered a year after in Japan on TV Tokyo. The purpose of the anime's creation was the promotion of Spin Master's line of Ionix construction bricks. Spin Master is a Canadian toy and entertainment company which started producing and promoting The Tenkai Knights toy line along with a new Pokémon line. The anime was adapted into a video game for Nintendo 3DS.

The two main characters in the [first episode](https://tenkai-knights.fandom.com/wiki/Two_Worlds) are [Guren Nash](https://myanimelist.net/character/103381/Guren_Nash) -- a boy who wears a red T-shirt, and has partially red hair -- and [Ceylan Jones](https://myanimelist.net/character/103383/Ceylan_Jones) -- a boy who wears a blue jacket and has blue hair. Guren is new in town, and after his first day at his new school, they go to a local shopping mall together and wander into a [mysterious antique shop](https://tenkai-knights.fandom.com/wiki/Shop_of_Wonders), where they find a pair of Lego-like bricks which can be transformed into mini-robot figures. The shop owner, [Mr. White](https://tenkai-knights.fandom.com/wiki/Mr._White), lets the boys keep the toys as a gift, and later that night, they have a dream about a battle between two robot-like beings.

The next day, they go back to the shop, but Mr. White is nowhere to be found, so they wander downstairs to the basement, where they discover a [device](https://tenkai-knights.fandom.com/wiki/Transdimensional_Portal) which transports them to a distant planet named [Quarton](https://tenkai-knights.fandom.com/wiki/Quarton). This planet is home to two warring races of robot-like beings, like the ones they saw in their dreams; the benevolent [Corekai](https://tenkai-knights.fandom.com/wiki/Corekai) and the malevolent [Corrupted](https://tenkai-knights.fandom.com/wiki/Corrupted_Army), led by [Vilius](https://tenkai-knights.fandom.com/wiki/Vilius_Tenkai_Dark_Tempest). On this planet, the boys inhabit the robot-like forms of [Bravenwolf](https://tenkai-knights.fandom.com/wiki/Bravenwolf_Tenkai_Firestorm) and [Tributon](https://tenkai-knights.fandom.com/wiki/Tributon_Tenkai_Iceblast), two of the legendary [Tenkai Knights](https://tenkai-knights.fandom.com/wiki/Tenkai_Knights_(team)) who aided the Corekai against the Corrupted in the past.

In the second episode, the boys meet two more Tenkai Knights, [Valorn](https://tenkai-knights.fandom.com/wiki/Valorn_Tenkai_Terrablast) and [Lydendor](https://tenkai-knights.fandom.com/wiki/Lydendor_Tenkai_Lightningstrike), who also turn out to be boys from Earth, and in later episodes they meet [Dromus](https://tenkai-knights.fandom.com/wiki/Dromus_Tenkai_Whirlwind) and [Venetta](https://tenkai-knights.fandom.com/wiki/Venetta).

The colour-schemes of the Tenkai Knights are as follows:

- Bravenwolf - red
- Tributon - blue
- Valorn - green
- Lydendor - yellow
- Dromus - black
- Venetta - pink